Passing artifacts through multi-project pipeline
I am currently triggering a downstream pipeline from a job as follow :
stages:
  - artifacts
  - trigger

build-job:
  stage: artifacts
  script:
    - ls -l doc/ 
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - doc/

trigger_job:
  stage: trigger
  trigger:
    project: path-to/my-project

Both jobs work perfectly with no error. The artifacts job shows me correctly all file in the doc folder. However, when trying to download the artifact from the triggered pipeline and then trying to display it, it shows me the files from the current project where the triggered pipeline is. Here is the CI configuration :
stages:          
  - download
  - use_artifacts

download_artifacts:
  stage: download
  script:
    - echo "Downloading artifacts from the triggering pipeline..."
    - echo "Artifacts:"
    - ls -l
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - doc/
    when: always

use_artifacts:
  stage: use_artifacts
  script:
    - echo "Using the downloaded artifacts..."
    - ls -l doc/

In the  download_artifacts job, it shows me the files from the project where this CI config is and in the use_artifacts, I then obviously get an error that such files do not exist.
I followed the following documentation :documentation on multi-project pipeline however I don't understand where the problem comes from. Any idea on something I missed ?
